# Why page from one domain is crawled under different domain name?

Tags: c#, seo, google-crawlers

I have 2 websites i.e. `www.sample1.com` and `www.sample2.com`. I have an item id i.e. **1**. This item 1 has a property called `channel` and actually belongs to `www.sample2.com`. But inside `www.sample1.com`, I have a logic to check if the requested item (in this case, item 1) has **`channel=sample2`**. If so, then I am redirecting it to `www.sample2.com`.

**My problem is**: even though item 1 belongs to `www.sample2.com`, it is crawled under `www.sample1.com` by google crawler. Any idea on how could I fix this?

**Update 1**
Both `www.sample1.com` & `www.sample2.com` share the same database.

**Update 2**
One solution I can think of is returning 404 or something relevant when item 1 is searched on `www.sample1.com` so that google will ultimately drop the page from `www.sample1.com`. But still, I do not understand why the page is rendered under `www.sample1.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Just check your redirection of that page when you open that page you will redirect to other channel then you have to fix it and don't panic about google result google also display old link in webmaster error just select and resolve error in webmaster day bay day your error is going to low if error is resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the SSL certificate.Check whether your site is matched with ssl certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ketan. Check whether the pages are redirecting properly. If everything is set up properly at your end, the reason you are facing the problem is Google has not yet cached and/or indexed your these pages recently. For this, you need to submit the crawl request to Google through Google Webmasters. I suggest to keep continue checking and monitoring the stats of Crawl Errors under Webmasters.

Once Google will cache your updated site, the issue will get resolved. The other thing you can do is go to Google URL removal request from its index and submit those pages which have been redirected from one site to another to delete the indexed pages from first website. This will help you out to de-index old pages from the first website quickly. Hope you get the point. Let me know if I can be of more help to you.

Answer (score -1):

When Google crawls websites, it tries to discover new and updated pages by following links. If it encounters a redirection, it should typically understand the nature of the redirect and treat it accordingly. However, there could be several reasons why the page is getting indexed under `www.sample1.com` instead of `www.sample2.com`.

Here are some potential reasons and solutions:

**1.Temporary Redirects:** If you're using a 302 (temporary) redirect, Google may not consider the move to be permanent and might still index the content under the original domain. Make sure to use a 301 (permanent) redirect to signal that the page has permanently moved.

**2.Crawl Timing:** It's possible that at the time of the crawl, the redirection wasn't effective or there were some intermittent issues. Check server logs to ensure that the redirect was in place when Googlebot visited the page.

**3. Canonical Tags:** Ensure you are using the canonical tag correctly. If the canonical URL on the content of `www.sample2.com` is set to `www.sample1.com`, then Google will consider the latter to be the preferred version to index.

**4. Internal Links:** If you have internal links within `www.sample1.com` pointing to the item 1 URL of `www.sample1.com` instead of the URL on `www.sample2.com`, Google might see this as a signal that the content is relevant to `www.sample1.com`.

**5. External Links:** If there are external websites linking to the item 1 URL on [www.sample1.com](http://www.sample1.com), it could contribute to Google indexing it under that domain.

**6. Robots.txt and Meta Robots:** Ensure that you haven't inadvertently blocked Google from crawling the item's URL on `www.sample2.com` via `robots.txt` or with a `noindex` meta tag.

**7. Delay in Updates:** Sometimes, even after you've made changes, Google might not reflect them immediately. It can take some time for Google to recrawl and reindex.

**Solutions:**

**1. Implement a 301 Redirect:** Make sure you're using a 301 redirect from `www.sample1.com` to `www.sample2.com` for that item.

**2. Canonical Tag:** Ensure the canonical tag on the page at `www.sample2.com` points to itself, not to any URL on `www.sample1.com`.

**3. Update Internal Links:** Ensure all internal links on both sites point to the correct URL for item 1 on `www.sample2.com`.

**4. Google Search Console:** Use Google Search Console to inspect the URL from `www.sample1.com` to see how Google views it. You can also request Google to recrawl specific URLs.

**5. Return 404:** As you mentioned, if it's not relevant for item 1 to be accessible on `www.sample1.com`, you can return a 404 error when it's accessed there. But, this should be a last resort as it may affect user experience if someone genuinely accesses the page from a valid source.

**6. Check Redirection Logic:** Make sure your logic is functioning correctly and that there aren't any conditions where the redirect might fail.

By implementing these checks and solutions, you should be able to resolve the issue and ensure that Google correctly indexes the content under the appropriate domain.